# Windows 10 universal: detect connected to Wifi

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, wifi

I found that our generic code to detect if a device is connected to Wifi does not work on non-phones.

`ConnectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile` is false even if the desktop computer is connected to Wifi.

What's the reliable, generic way to check if any Windows 10 device including phones, desktops and XBox devices are connected to a Wifi network?

Comment: Tested it with a Laptop, system version is 10586, connected to Wifi, this property is true, can't reproduce your problem. You can also try to use [getNetworkConnectivityLevel() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel.aspx) to get current network connectivity level.

Comment: Same here. It works for me on my Laptop and phone.

Comment: On my laptop both IsWwanConnectionProfile and IsWlanConnectionProfile are false.